# Doing PHP word processing

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, odbc

I have retrieved data from a MSSQL server table.
I was able to display them thanks to a query.
I would like to be able to modify these data without touching the table

For example the values which are in 1 for enc_paye would display ("Order in preparation) and enc_prepared (Order ready)

Also I would like to know if it is possible to remove the text from the table and only recover the data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Espace Client</title>
</head>
<body>
        <center><div class="Informations">
     <?php
            //CONNEXION ODBC SERVER//
            $dsn="";
            $user="";
            $password="";
            $conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user, $password);

            //REQUETES
            $sql = <<<EOF
                    SELECT top 10 [enc_cmd_num], [enc_paye], enc_prepared, enc_emporte, enc_heure_fab_fin, enc_ext_ref
                    FROM [encaissement]
                    WHERE enc_date= '20221130'
                    EOF;

            $results = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
            odbc_result_all($results);


            //CONDITION
            echo "<table>";
                while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results)) {
                    switch($resultrow['enc_paye']){
                    case 0:
                        echo "Commande en attente paiement";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        echo "Commande en cours de préparation";
                        break;
                    default: echo "<td>Unknown</td>";
                }

            }
            echo "</table>";


?>
</div></center>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see any text in your table? It's unclear what the problem is. If you want to display some text on-screen based on the numeric value in the database table, you can either use a CASE statement in the SQL, or some simple conditions in the PHP code which does the display.

Comment: I may have expressed myself badly, but the values that are present on the screen, I would like to change them by text without changing directly in the database

Comment: You said `remove the text from the table`...what text do you mean?

Comment: `change them by text`...do you mean what I said above - i.e. instead of showing the numeric values from the database, you would show some related piece of text? If so, then I suggested 2 solutions in my first comment.

Comment: Yes, that's right, replace the values 1 or 0 by text.
But can we modify sql data in php ? It will not be compatible ?

Comment: Huh? PHP will just send a SQL query to the database. If it's a valid query in SQL then you can send it from PHP code or from anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks to you for your precious help. But i need to use CASE , the problem its a have no idea how to use this

Comment: Well have you started by looking up the syntax for it? It's not clear where/how you're stuck

Comment: It's done ! I tried to debug now but thats the same thing

Comment: Thanks. `odbc_result_all($results);` will be causing your raw table data to output, still. DuckDensity already told you to remove that. And why did you change DuckDensity's code so much? It's fine to change the wording, but you have removed some of the HTML formatting, which will make it not a valid HTML table, and may mean you cannot see the data output properly. If you don't understand HTML table markup, then don't mess with that.

Comment: Thanks , its works now. Appreciate that

Comment: Good. You should mark DuckDensity's answer as accepted then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be storing status information about the order in different columns. I would suggest just using one column with different status numbers.

Perhaps:

```
0 - "Order received"
1 - "Order in preparation"
2 - "Order ready"
3 - "Order dispatched"
```

You can then use a switch statement in PHP to select between the text options

For example:

```
echo "<table>";
while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    switch($resultrow['enc_paye']){
        case 0:
            echo "<td>Order received</td>";
            break;
        case 1:
            echo "<td>Order in preparation</td>";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "<td>Order completed</td>";
            break;
        case 3:
            echo "<td>Order dispatched</td>";
            break;
        default: echo "<td>Unknown</td>";
    }
    // print some other fields in table data fields
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

The `odbc_result_all` function has been deprecated, so ideally you shouldn't use it.

** Edited following comments from @Adyson **

Comment: Thank you for your help.
The problem is that when I execute this code, it gives me the error : 

Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, resource given

Comment: You'll need to use `odbc_fetch_array` as someone else commented above. Variable names will get confusing when reused now, but you'll need `$results= odbc_fetch_array($results);` to work with your query excution and that code.

Comment: So i change the line : foreach($results as $resultrow){  to odbc_fetch_array and replace the line odbc_result_all($results); to $results= odbc_fetch_array($results)
Is that right ?

Comment: No, just put it somewhere before the `foreach`. Your query returns a resourse. Calling `odbc_fetch_array` on that resource returns a record set, and `foreach` can then be used to process the records one at a time.

Comment: nothing happen , thats the same parse error : Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, resource given

Comment: @DuckDensity not quite. odbc_fetch_array returns a single row of data. You'd need a while loop to call that until it returns false (i.e. there are no more rows to process). e.g. `while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results) { ...` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php.

Comment: @Adyson. Thank you for your comment, I've updated my answer. I am not overly familiar with the ODBC functions as I usually use PDO.

Comment: @DuckDensity me neither, I've never used it myself. But a quick trip to the documentation can usually solve that kind of thing :-)

Comment: @DuckDensity Thank you for your help. The problem is that now it is not the error of the foreach but the echo...

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "echo

Comment: @SHEYPT that's just a typo. `while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results) {` is missing another `)` just before the `{` to close the first `(`. If you have a decent IDE, it should highlight that to you.

Comment: @ADyson Indeed it works better, however no text appeared naked was changed.

Comment: @SHEYPT have you tried to debug it at all, then?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, even when i debug, the values remain at 1

Comment: @SHEYPT I don't see how, because this code in here doesn't output any numbers. Have you checked whether it enters the loop, even? It's not clear what your debugging effort actually consisted of. The only way I can think it would still be showing numbers is if you didn't remove the call to `odbc_result_all($results);` yet.

Comment: @ADyson First I connect to my database and make a selection of the values I want to retrieve and modify.

Secondly I then took the code that was provided to me by modifying only the text that I wanted 

I can provide the code here

Comment: @SHEYPT you can edit your question if you want to show us the code you're now using.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch your ODBC-result as an array:

```
$ODBCcontent = odbc_fetch_array($results);
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I insert your line of code...

Comment: You now have in $ODBCcontent what `odbc_result_all($result);` put to screen. To see what it contains, use something like `print_r($ODBCcontent);`. IIRC this gives you an associative array, so the keys should be corresponding to the table headline. I have no ODBC result to try it out. However, in this array is a representation of the data you can modify the way you need it.