# Delete table name in html css php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

My problem is the following:
I made display the characteristics of my table [enc_cmd_num] in php, the problem is that I want to display only the data and not the column name.

Here is my code :

```
 <?php
            //CONNEXION ODBC SERVER//
            $dsn="";
            $user="";
            $password="";
            $conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user, $password);

            //REQUETES
            $sql = <<<EOF
                    SELECT top 10 [enc_cmd_num]
                    FROM [encaissement]
                    WHERE enc_date= '20221130'
                    EOF;

            $results = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
            odbc_result_all($results);
```

[image: Screen of the result]

Comment: The table name isn't being displayed in your image though, just the column name and the data.

Comment: I misspoke, it is the name of the column that I want to delete

Comment: Then [edit] your questin to be representative of what you *actually* want. And [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It works, I just modified it.

Comment: Use a loop over all the rows, just like you were shown in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74861439/doing-php-word-processing). You cannot modify what `odbc_result_all` outputs - and it's [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-result-all.php) too, so it will eventually not work at all...you were already told in your last question to stop using it. That guidance also says _"This function is not supposed to be used in production environments; it is merely meant for development purposes, to get a result set quickly rendered."_

Comment: But when you talk about making a loop? What does that mean?

Comment: Huh? Like I said, we showed you in your last question. The `while` loop, using `odbc_fetch_array`. It was only yesterday...have you forgotten already? You can always go back and look

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but I only want to remove the name of the table and not change the numbers into letters.

Comment: Well then don't use the bit which changes the numbers into letters...just output the data items. It's the _loop_ which is the relevant bit. You need to loop through each row of data. What you do inside the loop is up to you. I am worried that actually you are missing some basic PHP knowledge if you cannot see that the act of looping through the rows, and the act of using the switch statement are separate things, and there is no requirement to use them both together. Try to actually understand what each line of your code is for, then you can change parts you don't need, and re-use other parts

Comment: I am still a beginner in PHP, but I still can't understand.
I will try to think about it...

Comment: Ok. Very simply: `while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results)) { echo $resultrow["enc_cmd_num"]."<br/>"; }` would echo the value from each row on a new line. Can you see now how I re-used the code which does the looping over each row of data from the database, but I changed the code which does the actual output, to something closer to what you want. The looping and the output are separate things. A key concept you need to grasp as a programmer is being able to re-use relevant bits of your code to achieve similar tasks, and changing bits which don't meet your requirements.

Comment: I'm not, particularly. That's really basic code. You just have to patiently work out what each part is doing (by experimentation, by looking at examples, and by reading documentation) so you understand its purpose, and then you can re-use it when you realise a similar purpose is needed in new code. If you're still struggling, take some more tutorials. We all start from the same place as a beginner :-)